# PHP array counting

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following php code where it goes through a loop and push elements to an array. I wanted to count elements in that array at the end of the loop. But it is not showing anything. Can someone please help me here?

```
<?php
  $i=0;
  $uphPerOperator = [];
    while($i<10){
     $uphPerOperator = array_push($uphPerOperator,$i);
     $i++;
    }
  $uphArrayCount = count($uphPerOperator);   
  echo $uphArrayCount; ?>
```

Comment: You use `array_push` the wrong way, see the php manual to see how this function works and what it is supposed to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the code working by changing it following way

```
<?php
  $i=0;
  $uphPerOperator = [];
    while($i<10){
     array_push($uphPerOperator,$i);
     $i++;
    }
  $uphArrayCount = count($uphPerOperator);   
  echo $uphArrayCount; ?>
```

Basically I changed `$uphPerOperator = array_push($uphPerOperator,$i);` to `array_push($uphPerOperator,$i);` and it works

Comment: A more idiomatic way to write it is `$uphPerOperator[] = $i;`

Comment: When answering you own answer you can mark it as accepted. I think you should also add link to the official documentation of tge `array_push` function